# Can't Import ggplot into my python code

Tags: python-3.x, python-ggplot

I'm trying to import `ggplot` into my project, but every time I run my code I get the following `ImportError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mo/SkyDrive/Python/Udacity/intro_to_ds_programming_files/lesson_4/plotting_python/gg_plot_quiz_student.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ggplot import *
ImportError: No module named 'ggplot'

Process finished with exit code 1`
```

I'm running Python 3.4 (anaconda) and the IDE I'm using is Pycharm. The `ggplot` library has ben installed using `pip` on the same directory as `anaconda`, but still not working. Am I doing something wrong?

The block of code that I'm trying to execute:

```
def lineplot(hr_year_csv):
    data = pd.read_csv(hr_year_csv)
    gg = ggplot(data, aes('yearID', 'HR')) + geom_point(color='red') + geom_line(color='red') + ggtitle('title') + xlab('yeadID') + ylab('HR')
    print (gg)

lineplot('hr_year.csv')
```

Comment: What happens when you check your pip's state using `pip freeze` ?  Is it in there ?

Comment: Are you using pip for python 2? Run `pip -V` and check that it is using python 3.x.

Comment: dshepherd - i'm using python 3.4. Anto - i ran pip freeze, i can see ggplot 0.5.8 in the list. Not sure what why i'm still can't import ggplot to my project.

Comment: try `import sys; print(sys.path)` and have a look if ggplot is imported in any of the path

Comment: Thanks Jan. tried that, but nothing about ggplot.

Answer (score 0):

It may sound silly, but... Have you tried to import the ggplot module?

```
from ggplot import *
```